# Adding a counter to a loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

On a broad question that I haven't been able to find for R:

I'm trying to add a counter at the beginning of a loop. 
So that when I run the loop `sim = 1000`:

```
if(hours$week1 > 1 and hours$week1 < 48) add 1 to the counter 
ifelse add 0
```

I have came across counter tutorials that print a sentence to let you know where you are (if something goes wrong): 
e.g

```
For (i in 1:1000) {
    if (i%%100==0) print(paste("No work", i)) 
}
```

But the purpose of my counter is to generate a value output, measuring how many of the 1000 runs in the loop fall inside a specified range.

Comment: Try to give a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) along with the expected output.

Comment: What is the problem with using your second suggested loop, and just maintaining a counter declared outside the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically had it. You just need to a) initialize the counter before the loop, b) use `&` instead of `and` in your `if` condition, c) actually add 1 to the counter. Since adding 0 is the same as doing nothing, you don't have to worry about the "else".

```
counter = 0
for (blah in your_loop_definition) {
    ... loop code ...
    if(hours$week1 > 1 & hours$week1 < 48) {
        counter = counter + 1
    }
    ... more loop code ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
if(hours$week1 > 1 & hours$week1 < 48) {
    counter = counter + 1
}
```

you could also use

```
counter = counter + (hours$week1 > 1 && hours$week1 < 48)
```

since R is converting TRUE to 1 and FALSE to 0.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```r
count = 0

for (i in 1:1000) {

  count = ifelse(i %in% 1:100, count + 1, count)

}

count

#> [1] 100
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is just to monitor progression coarsely, and you're using Rstudio, a simple solution is to just refresh the environment tab to check the current value of i.